# Trying to create a string that includes a time/date value using Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows

I am trying to create a string value that I will ultimately search for as a filename. The format is as follows: "FILE_NAME_NEEDED_PP_YYYYMMDD.TXT" where date stamp will equal actual date.

```
require 'date'
require 'time'

myDate = time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
staticName = "FILE_NAME_NEEDED_PP_"
staticExt = ".TXT"
fileName = 'staticName' + "#{myDate}" + 'staticExt'
puts fileName
```

However when I run the above I get "**`<main>': undefined local variable or method` time' for main:Object (NameError)**"

Comment: What is `time` supposed to be here? Do you mean `Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d')`? Your filename string will also be incorrect, you likely meant `filename = "#{staticName}#{myDate}#{staticExt}"`. Unrelated, but Ruby convention is to use snake_case (not camelCase) names for variables.

Comment: Dave... that totally worked sir. Been struggling with this for some time now. Coming from PERL this scripting lang has quite the learning curve. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare the `time` variable. One more thing you are not appending `staticExt` properly. Use the below code

```
require 'date'
require 'time'

time = Time.now

myDate = time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
staticName = "FILE_NAME_NEEDED_PP_"
staticExt = ".TXT"
fileName = 'staticName' + "#{myDate}" + "#{staticExt}"
puts fileName
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input and explanation Chakreshwar.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Your posted code has a number of things wrong with it, including:

1. Incorrect method invocation of [Time#strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Time.html#method-i-strftime).

   You need to invoke #strftime on a valid Time, Date, or DateTime object like [Time.now](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Time.html#method-c-now).
2. Unnecessary require statements.

   [Time](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Time.html) is automatically accessible as part of Ruby's core.
3. Use of fixed strings rather than variables to form a new string.

   Single-quoted strings are not variables. You're just appending strings when you call:

   ```
    'staticName' + Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d") + 'staticExt'
    #=> "staticName20200710staticExt"
   ```

### Solution

Here's some refactored code that works, using [Kernel#sprintf](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for readability:

```
date        = Time.now.strftime "%Y%m%d"
static_name = "FILE_NAME_NEEDED_PP_"
static_ext  = ".TXT"
filename    = sprintf "%s%d%s", static_name, date, static_ext

filename
#=> "FILE_NAME_NEEDED_PP_20200710.TXT"
```